# Dock Icons behaving like they'd be locked, but they are not?

Tags: snow-leopard, dock

I just noticed a weird behavior on my dock. The icons seem like if they'd be locked but in fact they are not. For instance when I try to move the icons around, I can take them and move them up. While I'm holding the touchpad, the icon moves with my cursor (that's not the case if the dock would be truly locked), but there won't open any spaces on where I'd like to move the icons to.

I also tried the commands

```
defaults com.apple.dock contents-immutable -bool FALSE
killall Dock
```

But in fact this doesn't change anything. Is there some additional flag which prevents adding new icons to the dock? I also tried some commands from this list here with no success: http://secrets.blacktree.com/edit?id=2279

Actually executing `defaults read com.apple.dock contents-immutable`results in "0". I'm also able to remove icons to the dock, but **not add new ones**.

Thx for any hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried deleting the Dock prefs?

Comment: of course that deleted my links, but apparently it worked...weird. anyway thx :)

Comment: When he said Delete he meant: “Backup and then delete” ;)

Comment: of course I did the backup of the file first, but restoring resulted in the same issue. There must have been something wrong with the file apparently. Now it works however :)